# How do I make tab control take over entire window in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, tabs, qt-creator

I want a tab control to "dock" to the entire window panel, in Qt Creator.  Now in Winforms and WPF this is super easy but in Qt its not working.

I've tried all the layouts, grid layouts, etc etc. it's just shrinking the tabs not making them grow to fill.  So please test a solution before telling me what the SHOULD BE OBVIOUS answer is cause its not working.

omg QQ this is driving me NUTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unsure what you are trying to achieve here - do you want the control to fill the client area?  Are you creating a QMainWindow-derived class or a QDialog-derived one?  If using QMainWindow then you'd make the tab control the central widget by calling `setCentralWidget`.  The tab control will then fill the main window's client area.  I have done this many times.

Or do you want the tab 'ears' to stretch?

Comment: Good answer although it still took me a while to find it, for thos who come here next this can be done in the constructor of the mainwindow.cpp file ... this->setCentralWidget(ui->tabWidget);